# Zero temperature Green function as limit of finite temperature Green function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, correlation-functions, greens-functions

Consider a system of $N$ fermions in a periodic box $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$. The Hamiltonian of the system is:
$$H_{N} = \sum_{k=1}^{N}(-\Delta_{x_{k}}-\mu) + \lambda \sum_{i< j}V(x_{i}-x_{j})$$
where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ is the chemical potential and $V$ is a sufficiently well-behaved interaction function. After second quantization, we consider the fermionic Fock space described by a second quantized Hamiltonian $H$.

Suppose we have a theory in finite temperature $\beta = 1/T > 0$. Let $\psi_{x}^{\pm}$ be creation and annihilation operators for fermions and, for $\beta \ge t_{i}$, $i=1,...,n$, $t_{i}\neq t_{j}$ for $i \neq j$, define the $n$-point (real time) Green's function:
$$S_{\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{n}, \beta}(x_{1},t_{1},...,x_{n},t_{n}) := (-1)^{\pi}\frac{\operatorname{Tr}(e^{-(\beta-t_{\pi(1)})H}\psi_{x_{\pi(1)}}^{\sigma_{\pi(1)}}e^{-(t_{\pi(1)}-t_{\pi(2)})H}\psi_{\pi(2)}^{\sigma_{\pi(2)}}\cdots \psi_{x_{\pi(n)}}^{\sigma_{\pi(n)}}e^{-t_{\pi(n)}H})}{\operatorname{Tr}e^{-\beta H}}.$$
Here, $\sigma = \pm 1$, $\pi$ is a permutation of $\{1,...,n\}$ and $(-1)^{\pi}$ is the parity of $\pi$.

Suppose, on the other hand, we have a zero temperature system. We then consider vacuum-vacuum correlations: if $\Omega$ denotes the ground state of $H$, then:
$$G_{\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{n}}(x_{1},t_{1},...,x_{n},t_{n}) = \langle \Omega,e^{-(\beta-t_{\pi(1)})H}\psi_{x_{\pi(1)}}^{\sigma_{\pi(1)}}e^{-(t_{\pi(1)}-t_{\pi(2)})H}\psi_{\pi(2)}^{\sigma_{\pi(2)}}\cdots \psi_{x_{\pi(n)}}^{\sigma_{\pi(n)}}e^{-t_{\pi(n)}H} \Omega\rangle$$

In the physics literature, it is claimed that $G$ is the limit $T \to 0$ of $S$, that is:
$$\lim_{\beta\to \infty}S_{\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{n}, \beta}(x_{1},t_{1},...,x_{n},t_{n})  =G_{\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{n}}(x_{1},t_{1},...,x_{n},t_{n}).$$

My question is: can this be proved rigorously? Using, say, functional analysis? Do we have any resources in the mathematical community addressing this result?

Comment: Side note: I believe you meant *$G$ is the limit $T\to 0$ of $S$*, but you wrote $G$ instead of $S$.

Comment: That is right! Thanks, it is correct now!